# Is there a way to emulate Add/Linear Dodge Blend mode in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, blend-modes

It does not matter if it requires additional work or layers to achieve it, I would appreciate it if anyone can let me know if there is a way. Perhaps a third party plug-in would also help if there is one.

Comment: At this point it becomes important to know what your output is designed to be like. Since illustrator is not the constraining factor but your output medium is. So even a plugin cannot change the limitation of pdf standards for example. So how do you plan to distribute your result?

Comment: I'm using adobe illustrator for digital painting (no actual printing of .ai file but .png) so I assume there would be no problem if a third party blend mode existed.

Comment: Any chance you could share an example image showing what you are trying to do, or what has failed.  Illustrator has a limited set of blend modes in comparison to Photoshop. As far as I know, there is no way to add blend modes. But there may be other ways to achieve what you want. Can't really tell without seeing something though.

Comment: Why dont you compose in photoshop then? But yeah i suppose if you have solids this could be done manually. i dont generally see that illustrator exposes enough info to do this in the API short of reimplementing entire renderer.

Comment: Blend modes merely change colors... while not always simple, especially with vector objects. It's possible to just change the color of objects to mimic blend modes. Sometimes this means objects must be expanded or trimmed/divided. But it's just color changing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a plug-in you can try a plug-out. Blending mode ADD is available in some other vector drawing programs. Affinity Designer is one of them. Versions 1.x were a light-year behind the capabilities of Illustrator, but versions since 2.0 have spurted much closer. Get the free trial, watch tutorials and try.

Illustrator has practically no tools for drawing nor editing bitmaps. Affinity Designer supports much better those who do not eschew mixing bitmaps and vector shapes.